# How to Control Padding Space Between X Axis Data Points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to control the spacing between, in this case, columns on a chart. I need access to the space between each bar and the space between each set of bars (the big white space between them in the picture). I have spent a bunch of time reading other posts and the documentation but for the life of me I can't find exactly what I am looking for.

Here is the jsFiddle of this example. It's a mash of things, being used for a POC.
https://jsfiddle.net/ek6za4m7/

I have already tried this

```
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      padding: 1
    }
  }
```

[image: "check out the space between them"[]

Comment: Post some code snippet so we can help you find the solution

Comment: @JimmySurprenant edited

Comment: What is your goal? How should the distances look?

Comment: @HalvorStrand I want the ability to spread it out and shorten it. Different requirements for different user groups within my company. When we embed these charts, too much panel is wasted on white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> groupPadding:0.4

property of column to increase or decrese the gap between group of columns.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            groupPadding:0.4        
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding